# How do I mock for all tests? jest.config.js or __mocks__?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

To mock a function for all tests in all suites, where do I put that code, and how is it written? Do I put it in a _ *mocks* _ folder, or inside jest.config.js?

Depending on where you're reading, different documentation says to do it different ways. Also, when one is mentioned, the other is not, so I cannot compare.

Can someone tell me once and for all?

Comment: You can do either. Why not make a choice? I don't think there's a wrong answer here

Comment: Score one for unoppinionated programming